# vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties return invalide memoryTypeCount

Tags: vulkan

By calling vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties then inspect my memories variable, it seems the memoryTypeCount value is incorrect. The memoryTypes array only contain 1 element. Why ?

[image: Debug view of my memories variable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your debugger has no idea that there is a relationship between `memoryTypes` and `memoryTypeCount`. All the debugger knows is what the types say. That means it knows is that `memoryTypeCount` is an integer, and `memoryTypes` is a pointer to a structure. It doesn't know that `memoryTypes` is a pointer to an *array* of structures, let alone that `memoryTypeCount` is the number of elements in this array. This is because C and C++ makes no type-based distinction between those concepts; any pointer to `T` could also be a pointer to an array of `T`.

So the debugger assumes that `memoryTypes`, like most pointers, is just a pointer to a single structure. And it displays it as such.

Comment: Indeed that totally logical. I'm a bit stupid at the moment